# How to connect custom authentication plugin to openid so I can authenticate it through steam?

Tags: plugin, development, joomla-4.x, login, authentication

I need to create a "login using steam button" for a website using Joomla, from my research I can gather up that using OAuth no longer works for Steam, so I'll have to create a custom authentication plugin for this. How to connect custom authentication plugin to openid so I can authenticate it through steam?

Comment: I am afraid your question is a little too broad for Stack Exchange. You are seeking a start to finish piece of development.  If you are not able to break down where you are stuck, this page will need to be closed as Too Broad / Needing More Focus. If you cannot develop the solution, you should probably hire a developer.

Comment: please [edit] this question to show your best attempt to self-solve and clarify where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be the instructions on how to do this:
https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla

Comment: I can appreciate that you are endeavouring to help; and citing the official docs is a solid strategy.  However, Stack Exchange does not want to be a web traffic router.  The advice that you give in an answer MUST stand up on its own (be just as informative if the link is removed). This is a predictable outcome when questions are too broad (cover too large of a development task). I now regret leaving the question open. Please attempt to transfer the advice from the docs to be statically written in your answer. Otherwise this answer may be converted to a comment under the question.

Comment: How would I connect this to the steam api using openID? it needs to be openID 2.0 not openID connect

Comment: the question is not too broad bro it is very specific, how to connect custom authentication plugin to openid so I can authenticate it through steam

Comment: These details should be edited into the question.  I am using the term "too broad" in that the topic is a whole development task which is comprised of many moving parts (which developers ordinarily get paid for).  These types of questions are not ideal on Stack Exchange because it puts the entire load on volunteers who give their expertise for free to strangers.  The best way to receive support and respect contributors is to do as much of the "lifting" as you can -- to lighten their load and encourage concise, accurate, insightful answers.

Comment: @mickmackusa: I wanted to make a comment, but I don't have enough rights yet.... But thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Gratia-Mira I don't like to interfere with well-intended contributions, but it would be remis of me to not uphold the universal principles/guidelines of Stack Exchange.  Anyhow, you now have earned the privilege to comment anywhere.